# Booking with Frontier: how to get the online travel-finder price but still book through Frontier?

Tags: tickets, bookings, frontier-airlines

I had previously bought airfare flying domestically in the USA on Frontier airlines, directly from Frontier.  Unfortunately, my reason to travel was postponed, so I also have to postpone my travel.

The value of my currently purchased flight (minus $99) will not be refunded to me and can only be applied to another Frontier ticket within 90 days of me cancelling my flight.

I went onto Google Flights to find the best flights for my postponed travel dates, which are still through Frontier, and was happy to see low prices listed:

[image]

However, when I click on the link to be taken to book directly on the Frontier website, I see this

[image]

A round-trip ticket that Google lists for $134 is over $500 on the Frontier website.  I realize this is [not an uncommon occurrence](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94409/discrepancies-between-flight-comparison-websites-and-airlines).  I checked that the other options Google lists (Orbitz, Priceline, etc.) are actually offering the tickets at those prices.  However, in order for me to apply the value of my currently purchased airfare (total value ~$200) I have to purchase the airfare directly from Frontier AFAIK.

- Is there any way I could apply the value of my current tickets to airfare purchased through a third-party site (not directly from Frontier)?
- Is there any way I can purchase airfare directly from Frontier for something much closer to the price that it's listed on Google?

**Edit:** I am flying between Trenton NJ (TTN) and Orlando FL (MCO).

**Second edit:** Just checked today and now Frontier and Google Flights are agreeing, and the plane ticket is even cheaper than the Google Flights quote yesterday.

Comment: Funny enough, I just tried to do the same thing and had the opposite problem -- Google was showing $261 for a DEN-DCA leg but when I clicked through to Frontier they gave me $141. (Also that $44 fare on 4/19 return looks fantastic.)

Comment: Maybe if you told us what airports you were flying between we could be of more help.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, I have done so, just added an edit.

Comment: I think often errant/expired results show up on such sites that you end up just not being able to get anywhere.   I had the same problem with Skyscanner recently... but then saw far down the page "Prices checked daily. Rates may change due to availability at time of reservation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there is no way to do this other than to book on the Frontier website.